how to import js file when i use astro frame
I wish to reference the js data file in the framework
---
import Layout from "../layouts/Layout.astro";
// import Card from "../components/Card.astro";
import Configs from "../data/configs";

console.log(Configs);
---

<Layout title="Strengths & Weaknesses"/>

<style></style>

This doesn't give me an output in my browser console.
use export same not working
const Configs = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "cover": "1.webp"
  }
]
export default Configs


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Try to put the console.log in <script> like this
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro';

---

<script>
import Configs from '../data/config';

console.log(Configs);
</script>

<Layout title="Welcome to Astro.">

See more details for the client side script:

Troubleshooting-Debugging with console.log()
Client-Side Scripts


Not entirely clear what framework you are using client side but some documentation for you to look through for this is here if working with React/Vue etc. Otherwise to run standard JS with all code contained within the .astro file then passing your console log within a script tag will get the outcome you want.
To summarise what is happening, you've written the import and console log within the --- brackets. This is marking code to run on server side for this page. This will result in the log only appearing within a server console, with the client being completely unaware of any of this happening. Adding the script tag and the console log within is you informing the client to print that log instead of the server.
Worth noting though if you are only wanting to examine the const in a console, then as I mentioned above it will be appearing in the terminal where you ran your command to host your dev code.
